# how to pick up correct value based on values from tow columns of onw dataframe comparing with value and name of the column of another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, comparison

df1:

```
Specie  Wagon
birch   42387837
birch   42092742
spruce  42385138
spruce  42250878
pine    42328609
pine    42328799
```

df2:

```
Wagon      birch    spruce  pine
42387837    51,7    58,45   59,17
42092742    51,7    58,45   59,17
42385138    51,7    58,45   59,17
42250878    51,7    58,45   59,17
42328609    51,7    58,45   59,17
42328799    51,7    58,45   59,17
```

What is the best way to reach output df1 look this:

```
Specie  Wagon   Volume
birch   42387837    51,7
birch   42092742    51,7
spruce  42385138    58,45
spruce  42250878    58,45
pine    42328609    59,17
pine    42328799    59,17
```

Thanks for advance for help

Comment: As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Some python code would come in handy as in... on wht kind of data structure are you holding those dataframes? Dicts? Lists of tuples?

Comment: In this case Lists.   But it is easy to transform back and forth!

Comment: Aren't you using pandas? How is df2.melt or df1.merge acceptable in an answer otherwise? I think it would be worth adding the pandas tag and mentioning the pandas framework in the tittle and making it explicit that you are specifically working with pandas dataframes, not with abstract dataframes that could otherwise be primitive lists or database querysets or some arbitrary generator.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep in mind next time. Thanks!  For me Dataframe associated only with Pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Use `melt` on df2, and `merge` with df1:

```
df1.merge(df2.melt(id_vars='Wagon', var_name='Specie', value_name='Volume'),
          on=['Wagon', 'Specie'])
```

output:

```
   Specie     Wagon Volume
0   birch  42387837   51,7
1   birch  42092742   51,7
2  spruce  42385138  58,45
3  spruce  42250878  58,45
4    pine  42328609  59,17
5    pine  42328799  59,17
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very usefull function df.melt()